# Apache + mod_wsgi + flask app: doing graceful restart due to receiving SIGUSR1 signal

Tags: python, apache, flask, apache2, mod-wsgi

I have `flask`/`python2.7`/`apache2`/`mod_wsgi` app and periodically I can see the following lines in apache log and my application gets restarted:

```
[mpm_event:notice] AH00493: SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart
[wsgi:error] Joining threads
```

I know that such "graceful restart" can happen if there was [segfault](https://talk.plesk.com/threads/apache-reload-graceful-restart-causes-apache-segfault.335534/), but as far as I can see there was no segfault in my case (no corresponding lines in log before line 'doing graceful restart'). Or maybe such event wasn't logged... anyway I suspect this is apache2 issue because `mpm_event` is apache2 internal entity ([docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/event.html)).

So my questions are:

1) How to check what's wrong in my case?

2) If this is default behavior (restarting if there is no activity for example) rather than issue - how to configure it and where?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because your system has `logrotate` setup to handle log rotation for Apache. It will send a graceful restart signal to Apache to have it reload while it swaps out the log files.

If this isn't desirable, don't have `logrotate` do that and use Apache's own mechanism for log file rotation.

Comment: Thank you for the great pointer! In my case the behavior was caused Certbot (letsencrypt). You can check the Certbot activity at `/var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log`.